# Probability of each outcome from dice notation

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the "dice notation", XdY means you rolls X number of Y-sided dices, and adds the results together to get the final outcome.

For example, on 3d3 distribution, you can get number from 3 to 9, and the probability of each number can be calculated as:

$P(X=3) = P(X=9) = \frac{1}{27}$

$P(X=4) = P(X=8) = \frac{1}{9}$

$P(X=5) = P(X=7) = \frac{2}{9}$

$P(X=6) = \frac{7}{27}$.

For other examples, on 1d4 distribution, you can get number from 1 to 4 equally likely, and on 4d1 distribution, you always get 4.

Can I get the explicit formula that gives the probability of each outcome (namely, Z) from XdY distribution? I want the function $f(X,Y,Z)$ that exactly returns the probability that we get outcome $Z$ from XdY distribution.

I know when $X$ becomes large, this approaches the normal distribution, but when $X$ is not that large (like 15~20), I need exact value here..

Comment: It looks straightforward to get a formula, what is the difficulty?

Comment: @almagest Is it that straightforward? I don't think so.. $f(10,10,48)$ needs crazy amount of calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let r.v. $S$ be the sum of $n$ dice, each with $m$ faces $1,...,m.$ The generating function for $S$ is 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{nm} P(S=j)x^j = \left[\frac xm+\frac {x^2}m+...+\frac{x^m}m  \right]^n $$
$$ =\frac{x^n}{m^n}(1-x^m)^n(1-x)^{-n}  $$ 
Binomial expansions: 
$$(1-x^m)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{nm}{n \choose k}(-1)^kx^{km}$$
$$ (1-x)^{-n}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {-n \choose i}(-1)^ix^i= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{n+i-1 \choose i}x^i  $$
For a fixed integer $j\ge n$ we need to find the coefficient of $x^{j-n}$ in the product of these two sums in order to find $P(S=j).$ If we multiply term $k$ of the first sum and term $i$ of the second, then this gives $x^{km+i}.$ So we need to require $km+i=j-n.$ For given $k$ I can solve for  $i=j-n-km.$ So now $k$ is the only index variable: 
$$P(S=j)=\frac {1}{m^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} {j-1-km \choose j-n-km} {n \choose k}(-1)^k  $$
example: $ n=3,m=3,j=6$
$$ P(S=6)=\frac{1}{3^3}\left[ {5 \choose 3}{3 \choose 0}-{2\choose 0}{3 \choose 1} \right]=\frac{7}{27}  $$

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is this term:

$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4...+x^m)^n$

m: number of sides

n: number of dices

Expand the term above and collect all the summands with $x^k$. The number of permutations with the sum k is the coefficient $c_k$, of $c_k \cdot x^k$

Example:

m=3

n=2

$(x+x^2+x^3)^2=x^2+2 x^3+\color{blue}{3 x^4}+2 x^5+x^6$

There are 3 permutations with the sum of 4.

$(3,1);(1,3);(2,2)$

Comment: To get the probability, you need to divide the coefficient by $m^n$

Comment: Yeah.. but I'm working on the explicit formula for each coefficient.

Comment: @fiverules What have you tried ?